# Separated text on one line side to another?

Tags: html, css

I want to make text like this:

[image: http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1303/22/3/33efdad184ec.jpg]

Look like this:

```
texttext:      textttt
ttttttttttt:   ttt215555
textt:         trtrtrt
```

But when I try, it looks like this:

```
texttext: textttt
ttttttttttt: ttt215555
textt: trtrtrt
```

My code that i'm currently using:

```
<div class="aligncenter" style="width: 700px; height: 1px; border-top: 1px dotted #999999; font-size: 0;">-</div>
Hours: Mon - Sun: 3:00 pm - 6:00 am Phone: 777777777777 Address: asd str. #14
<div class="aligncenter" style="width: 700px; height: 1px; border-top: 1px dotted #999999; font-size: 0;">-</div>
```

I've solved it like this (wordpress):
http://jsfiddle.net/SEcfh/

```
<table border="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px;">Phone:</td>
<td>+999 999 999 999</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px;">Phone:</td>
<td>+999 999 999 999</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 80px;">Phone:</td>
<td>+999 999 999 999</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: <div class="aligncenter" style="width: 700px; height: 1px; border-top: 1px dotted #999999; font-size: 0;">-</div>
Hours:   Mon - Sun: 3:00 pm - 6:00 am
Phone:   777777777777
Address: asd str. #14 
<div class="aligncenter" style="width: 700px; height: 1px; border-top: 1px dotted #999999; font-size: 0;">-</div>

Comment: I have created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AxP3s/. but it doesn't seem as you described. so make change here and then describe the problem

Comment: Added @user2200585 code to post.

Comment: In wordpress I've made it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/SEcfh/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap` to preserve spaces in your text.  You could also use a layout with `<table>`s for tabular data, or a definition list `<dl> / <dt> / <dd>` setup with fixed width terms.

Comment: +1 for recommending a `dl` structure, that's what I'd do first, then amend the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use `white-space: pre` because you'll manually have to add the right amount of spaces to your text.

Using spans with a certain width, wrapped in a div with width 2x, you can easily achieve this. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/qaTDN/

Answer (score 0):

This is tabular data, so why not put it in a `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

TO break a line or word after certain width you can use this CSS tag:

**word-wrap: break-word;**